# How to make a list of image preview

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code for image preview

```
$("#weeklyOfferImages").change(function(){
    readURLWeekly(this);
});
function readURLWeekly(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('.weeklyPreview').append('<img data-src="holder.js/140x140" src="'+e.target.result'"class="offer-image img-polaroid"/>');
        },
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

this code only display one image at a time.
How can i make it display multiple images. for example the files object contains 4 files.

Comment: You may want to specify where you want to 'display multiple images'. In the same '.weeklyPreview' container, perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you only display "0" -> `img input.files[0]`

dynamic with `length`  - iterating the whole array

```
function readURLWeekly(input) {
    if(input.files)
        for(var i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++) {
            if (input.files[i]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(e) {
                    $('.weeklyPreview').append('<img data-src="holder.js/140x140" src="' + e.target.result + '" class="offer-image img-polaroid"/>');
                },
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this :

```
$("#weeklyOfferImages").change(function(){
    readURLWeekly(this);
});
function readURLWeekly(input) {
    if (input.files) {
        for (var i=0;i<4;i++) {
            if (input.files[i]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('.weeklyPreview').append('<img data-src="holder.js/140x140" src="'+e.target.result'"class="offer-image img-polaroid"/>');
                },
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The 'else' clause is unnecessary

Comment: else is just a optimization so that loop terminates in case we have only 2 files for example..

Comment: I think you may not really know if there are only 2 files